# How to enable Ctrl+Click navigation in CLion, like VScode does?

Tags: visual-studio-code, header, ide, clion

I am developing in a nice environment (C++/Linux/CLI/Makefile/ARM/gcc/Embedded) and I like to open my code with whatever IDE is not already open in another desktop: VSCode, Sublime, CLion, atom, ...

I am very impressed with VSCode as I can almost ctrl+click anything: header, declaration, definition, ...

I was just wondering how/if I could obtain the same behavior within CLion?

Googling around shows me CMake-based answers, which of course are not acceptable.

(I *do* have the magic 3-lines CMakeList.txt (*) file at the root of my project, urging immediately the real Makefile to do its proper job, so I can compile within/from CLion):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1) 
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE "STATIC_LIBRARY") 
project(my_project)

include_directories(.) 
include_directories(lib/)
include_directories(lib/*)
include_directories(inc/) 
include_directories(inc/*)
include_directories(com/)
include_directories(com/*)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")

add_custom_target(my_project COMMAND make -C ${my_project_SOURCE_DIR}
                         CLION_EXE_DIR=${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to enable navigation, you need a project file to tell your IDE what settings/flags/defines is the source code compiled with, because of C/C++ preprocessor, and because makefiles are so free-form programming language.

Some VERY basic C/C++ navigation is available in CLion even without any project file. Maybe your VSCode takes the default parsing a few steps further, or maybe you have VSCode with Makefile plugin enabled.

CLion currently supports 3 types of projects: `CMakeLists.txt`,  [compilation database](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/compilation-database.html) and `Makefile`.

To enable the advanced parsing, please either create a `CMakeLists.txt` (and quote it in your question if it doesn't work), or generate a compilation database project for the Makefiles, [CLion documentation tells how to do it](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/managing-makefile-projects.html).

Comment: Is this helping? Mmh the compilation database sounds like a nice/new lead...but can't really add something more. I wish the IDE could find his way by itself, like VSCode (or PyCharm, btw)

Comment: I expanded the answer a bit. Sorry, I don't understand what "can't really add something more" is about. Note that Python doesn't have any kind of conditional compilation or strict module dependencies.

Comment: Answer accepted: I hate to be the one saying that, but indeed "playing" the game of CLion (e.g. with a real CMakeLists.txt, my first one, ...and for x-compiling :crazy_eyes: ) solves it all. You were right saying that anything 'more/better' in VScode is only a not-so-ugly-side-effect. But we are professionals and won't stand by side-effects for our daily work indeed.